# Open sourcing an android studio library project and allowing others to include as gradle dependency

Tags: android, github, android-studio, gradle

I would like to open source a library project that I am working on in android studio (hosted on GitHub) and allow others to include the project as a dependency.

Example:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.test:myproject:1.0'
}
```

I've done some research, and have only discovered how to create a module and import it locally within my project. Does anyone know the necessary steps to take to achieve what I want?

Comment: you will have to publish the library on bintray (easiest way). You can use the following lib to help you release it https://github.com/novoda/bintray-release

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicly you can publish your app on a public repository like maven or jCenter. The easiest way is to published on [bintray](https://bintray.com/), it's free for open source public library. You can use the [following library](http://github.com/novoda/bintray-release) to help you

Answer (score 0):

Also, look into [jitpack.io](https://jitpack.io/). It is easily the quickest way for getting a JVM projects up and ready especially if you're already using Github. [Here's the extra docs for it as well.](https://github.com/jitpack/jitpack.io)